# CTRL+F5 in Google Chrome in XFCE

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce

I have installed Ubuntu with unity by default, but compiz + java develop is less then sufficient with a ATI graphic card, so, I installed the `xubuntu-desktop` package.

The problem is: In Google chrome (which I use to test my web apps), when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (clean cache and refresh), it simply does nothing.

I think this is some issue with XFCE keyboard shortcuts.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generally in XFCE keyboard shortcuts the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is configured to switch to workspace 5, if you do not have any workspace 5, then hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> wont do anything.

To resolve it goto,

> Applications Menu > Settings > Settings Manager > Window Manager

check the Keyboard tab, and find the option which has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> configured as short-cut key,

clear that short-cut key.

you should be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> key now for chrome.

Comment: Clearing the key didn't succeed for me, I had to edit it and assign an arbitrary rarely used key combination for it.

Answer (score 0):

As alternate, you can edit ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml and remove settings for Primary + F5 shortcut. And don't forget to restart the system after it.