# Xubuntu on VirtualBox VM does not see CTRL-Fn key combinations

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, function-keys

VirtualBox 6.1.18
Host: Windows 10
Guest: Xubuntu 20.04
Guest extensions installed and active

None of the `CTRL`+`Fn` key combinations seem to work in any program I tried (Visual Studio Code, LibreOffice, etc.)

Interestingly, `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`Fn` combinations seem to work fine.

Please advise.

**Edit:**

I tried the [Keyboard Event Viewer](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html) inside the VM.  When the `CTRL` key was pressed, none of the `F1`-`F12` key presses registered.  They did register when the `CTRL` key was not pressed, or when it was pressed in combination with the `SHIFT` key.

Similarly, I see the same when I run `xev | grep -E -A3 "^KeyPress"` (as suggested in a comment to another question)

This happens with the built-in Thinkpad keyboard, with the wireless Logitech K800, and with the VirtualBox on-screen "soft keyboard".  Remapping the HOST key combination did not help.

I am at a loss.

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/92770/1175065).
It was an XFCE issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with XFCE rather than virtualBox.
By default, it maps `CTRL`+`Fn` combinations to switch to the corresponding workplaces.

See the answer to another question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/92770/1175065).